Making batch file to run .sql files and dynamic import
Couple of problems.

Need to run a .sql file from batch. (do they run the queries from top to bottom kinda thing?) Having some problems connecting to psql, database, and schema.
In one of the querys I make a temp table with the correct columns and copy a csv and then insert that into my main table, I want to make that process with a dynamic csv name (ex. solicitation%todaysdate%.csv)
I want to make a batch that creates a back up of the database.

To make this a bit easier to understand:
the temp table process is as shown
create temp table "import"(
customer_name varchar(1000),
Quote_number varchar(1000),
Part_number varchar(1000),
Order_Status varchar(1000),
Bid_Total varchar(20),
Unit_Price varchar(20),
Customer_Part_number varchar(1000),
Most_Recent_Unit_Cost varchar(1000),    
Most_Recent_Quantity varchar(1000),
Total_Potential varchar(1000),
Competitors varchar(1000),
Solicitation_number varchar(1000),
NSN varchar(1000),
Date_Accessed date,
Closing_Date date,
Quantity_Requested varchar(1000),
Person_name varchar(1000),
Purchase_request_no varchar(1000),
RFQ_Forms varchar(1000),
Tech_Docs varchar(1000),
Tech_Docs_Links varchar(1000),
Qualifications varchar(1000),
Nomenclature varchar(1000),
Reason varchar(1000),
Spec_Summary varchar(1000),
FAI varchar(1000)
)

copy "import"
FROM 'C:\Users\yuju\SQL_Data\solicitation.csv' 
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;

insert into "Dibbs".dibbs_db (customer_name, quote_number,part_number,order_status,bid_total,unit_price,customer_part_number,
most_recent_unit_cost, most_recent_quantity, total_potential, competitors, solicitation_number, nsn_part_number, date_accessed,
closing_date, quantity_requested, person_name, pr_number, request_for_quotation_forms, tech_docs, tech_docs_links,
qualifications, nomenclature, reason, spec_summary, fai)
select *
from "import";

Where I manually change the csv name everyday to import.

You stated your intent but the only clear question is the "do they run the queries from top to bottom kinda thing?". Yes, they do. Please share the error messages you're getting when "connecting to psql" if you need assistance with that. The dynamic csv name can be handled with a psql variable you set with the -v option. For backups, take a look at the manual or consult your cloud provider's docs, if it's a hosted db.

For what system is your batch file? Is it windows? What does your batch file look like now? Do you use parameters in your batch file?

Yes its for windows. Im guessing I will need parameters for the dynamic import.
